# ChartJS: add a clickable text in title

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using `ChartJS` to draw a line chart. I want to update the chart with the different dataset but that is another case. Right now i am having trouble in adding a button in the title because no `callback` function is available for this. Any thing from i can get help ?

Comment: Hey did you found a solution for this? I'm also struggling to add links to titles ...

Comment: @necker no i have read the documentation and issues in the github. There is no support available for that. However let me tell you how i have hack this.

Comment: @necker i have added the answer below please check if it makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5080#issuecomment-353889337.) issue on github.

There are two points mentioned:

1- You cannot have a hyperlink inside the `canvas`.

2- There is a solution to make title clickable but this makes whole one point to another point clickable not only text but the `white space` also.

**My solution** :  what I did was to use a simple hack; I hide the title by giving it `display :false` and then add an external link to it. Line adding a link into the `div`. And upon clicking it I was changing the chart.

You can control the chart by using any external element but there are some limitation on manipulating the chart from the elements of the charts itself.

I hope it may help the future readers.